# Event after selecting point

Tags: anychart

is there some event fired when selecting a point on a map?
Currently I am using this

```
series.listen('pointClick', function(event) {
}
```

but to fire this event you have to double click on a point. the first click selects a point and the second click fires this event.

how can I listen to the "point select event"?

```
series.listen('pointSelect', function(event) {
}
```

does not work.

Thanks!

Comment: Reading the anychart-docs over here: http://docs.anychart.com/7.12.0/Common_Settings/Event_Listeners it seems that 'pointClick' should do what you want. Could you show us an example with your non-working code? alternatively, it seems there's a `pointsSelect`-event. is this what you are looking for?

Comment: You can see the same behaviour as in this fiddle from the playground: http://playground.anychart.com/api/7.12.0/core/anychart.core.Base.listen-plain -> selecting a point without clicking it a second time does not raise the counter. Also editing this example with "pointSelect" or "pointsSelect" does not work: http://jsfiddle.net/mmintel/0zt0sj8q/

Comment: this seems to be a bug in anychart then for me. `pointClick` and `pointDblClick` are doing exactly the same thing. Even `click` just works the second time (but then as intended). Sorry for you, no idea how to fix this. I would address this to them for it'S a commercial library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both, pointClick and pointSelect events should work. We have identified this as a bug and will fix it in release 7.13.0, ETA: End of Feb 2017.

For now, please use pointsSelect event. It also works for multi-series chart.

```
map.listen('pointsSelect', function(e) {});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gpd5v5bz/3/

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It seems pointsSelect only works for the map, not for a series, but that's enough for me now!